# Bootstrap-4 display classes don't work

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-4-beta

I'm working with Bootstrap 4 beta at the moment and everything works fine, but I have one problem... the display classes like d-none, d-inline, d-inline-block... don't have any effect. Everything else works just fine and I don't understand why they don't work.

for example:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">                
        <div class="col-xs-12">
            <h1 class="bg-success d-inline">Test</h1> <h1 class="bg-success d-inline">Test2</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Those h1 elements are still displayed as block elements. has anyone an idea where the problem could be?

Comment: But it is working for me when using this version: <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-PsH8R72JQ3SOdhVi3uxftmaW6Vc51MKb0q5P2rRUpPvrszuE4W1povHYgTpBfshb" crossorigin="anonymous">

Comment: i'm using the beta2 version too, but it won't work. every other bootstrap class seams to work. only the d-* classes doesn't work. I know that this is not an overall problem with bootstrap itself, I watched videos and read tutorials and every where it seams to work just fine. But in my case it doesn't. Very strange, especially because everything else works.

Comment: Can you share your CSS link here?

Comment: I'm not using CDN. I'm working with laravel and installed bootstrap 4, so I'm using an local version.

Comment: Then on CSS file just search by class names ".d-inline" if you found then should look have other CSS impact or not. If not found then in your version not not available these features. Sometime we added CSS file from one version but take markup from other version.

Comment: Ok I think I found the problem. The CSS file has only the display classes with breakpoints, like d-md-inline... but the overall display classes d-inline, d-block, and so on are missing.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I think I found the problem. The CSS file has only the display classes with breakpoints, like d-md-inline... but the overall display classes d-inline, d-block, and so on are missing.